# TypeScript extend JQuery under Namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces, typescript, extending

I'm trying to extend the default `JQuery` interface and the default object `jQuery` by a function in TypeScript

**Code**

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />

namespace MyNameSpace {
    var $ = jQuery;
    export interface JQuery {
        test(options: Object): JQuery;
    }
    $.fn.test = function(options: Object): JQuery {
        if (this.length === 0) {
            console.log('Error!');
            return this;
        }
        console.log(options);
        return this;
    }
    export var testBody = function() {
        jQuery('body').test({ 'HELLO': 'TEST' });
    }
}
```

**The Problem**

Now I'm running the following code in my console:
`tsc -m amd -t ES5 Test.ts -d`

I'm getting this error: `Test.ts(17,19): error TS2339: Property 'test' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.`

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works for me:

```
/// <reference path="typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />

interface JQuery {
    test(options: Object): JQuery;
}

namespace MyNameSpace {
    var $ = jQuery;

    $.fn.test = function(options: Object): JQuery {
        if (this.length === 0) {
            console.log('Error!');
            return this;
        }
        console.log(options);
        return this;
    };
    export var testBody = function() {
        jQuery('body').test({ 'HELLO': 'TEST' });
    }
}
```

**EDIT: 2nd solution**

```
/// <reference path="typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />

namespace MyNameSpace {

    interface JQueryX extends JQuery {
        test(options: Object): JQuery;
    }

    $.fn.test = function(options: Object): JQuery {
        if (this.length === 0) {
            console.log('Error!');
            return this;
        }
        console.log(options);
        return this;
    };

    export var testBody = function() {
        let a:JQueryX = <JQueryX>$('body');
        a.test({ 'HELLO': 'TEST' });
        // OR
        (<JQueryX>$('body')).test({ 'HELLO': 'TEST' });
    }
}
```

You can make the `testBody` nicer by some refactoring.