# How do I extend for a single file?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a site with 10 pages, which share a Typescript file, and also each page has its own specific Typescript file. One page has a JQuery plugin, `timepicker`, so I extend the JQuery object using:

```
interface JQuery {
    timepicker(options:any):JQuery;
}
```

However I don't want any of the other TypeScript files to have timepicker on the `JQuery` object. How can I extend it just for this file?

It doesn't let me extend `JQuery` inside a namespace.

Can modules help? I have no need to import or export anything, so I am not sure it is appropriate, or how to use modules.

Comment: If every page has its own Typescript file, why don't you just add that interface line only to the specific page that needs it? By the way, strictly speaking you are not extending the jQuery object by writing an interface that is also called jQuery :)

Comment: @Kokodoko That is what I do, however all Typescript files in the project see this interface, and show `timepicker` on `JQuery`.

Comment: It is probably just your IDE that sees the `timepicker` interface and applies it to your whole project. Perhaps you could use namespaces to differentiate between pages and have some interfaces only in some namespaces. `namespace page10 { interface bla{ } }`

Comment: @Kokodoko As I mentioned, you can't extend an interface in a namespace as that simply hides the main `JQuery` interface. See [Merging Interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).

Comment: Just using modules won't fix it. If you want to turn a file into a module even though you don't want to import or export anything, you can just do `export {};` and your file will be treated as a module by `tsc`. You can try it, but as I said, that's not a fix, by itself. All of my TS code is modules, and as soon as jQuery is used by any module, its types are visible in all modules, whether or not the module imports `"jquery"`. :-/ That's just the way its definition file is set.

Comment: @wezten are you using a loader/bundler? Are modules even an option?

Comment: @AluanHaddad I'm not using modules, but I could. Would they help? Louis wrote that they won't.

Comment: @wezten yes but it's not worth it just to accomplish this.

Comment: @wezten My comment was meant to convey that *merely* turning your files into modules won't help. There may be a solution that would turn your files into modules *and* would also do *something else* in addition to that. (That's why I wrote "*just* using modules..." and "...not a fix, *by itself*.")

Comment: @AluanHaddad It would be worth using modules for this - I have multiple plugins and global variables per page. Please write an answer explaining how to use modules to solve my issue, and I'll give it the bounty.

Comment: @wezten OK but be aware that my answer will be opinionated as you need to adopt a module loader or bundler as part of your tool chain.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Sure.

Comment: Thanks but I realized my idea won't work. Using modules would let you encapsulate the type level augmentation of jQuery but once any of your files consume the augmentation, the `timepicker` will appear available in all of them. Actually, while not one-to-one, it does match reality since loading the timepicker plugin mutates `$.fn.prototype`

Comment: Have you look into this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277521/typescript-extend-jquery-under-namespace

Comment: Do you really need to extend to accomplish this? You're just trying to import jQuery's timepicker for use in a particular page, right?

Comment: @MarkCooper Right. How can I do that without extending?

Comment: @wezten it really depends on your project setup. How are you including jQuery and timepicker on the page you need them? Are they being included via markup or requires?

Comment: @MarkCooper That will add `test` to all files.

Comment: @wezten what is `test`? I think more info is needed...

Comment: @MarkCooper My previous comment was meant for Mark Dave Ingalla. Sorry about that, I got mixed up with both Marks.

Answer (score 1):

You could name the interface something more reflective of what it is—something like:

```
interface JQueryWithTimePicker extends JQuery {
    timepicker(options: any): JQuery;
}
```

Then your one file that needs the timepicker can use the JQuery object downcast to JQueryWithTimePicker.

I use this strategy sometimes when I need to add properties to DOM nodes.  Something like:

```
interface MyTreeElement extends HTMLElement
{
    Nodes: TreeNode[];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can literally include the following in your page markup:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
```

And then just do whatever with time picker by making use of the following trick to get a handle on jQuery:

```
declare var jQuery: any;

export class Whatever {
    private timePicker = jquery.timePicker
}
```

It's super hacky, but I think it would work.

Comment: Then I don't have intellisense for all `JQuery` objects.

Comment: @wezten This will keep your instances clean in terms of the actual runtime. In terms of your IDE, that tends to be an all or nothing thing. The jQuery docs are super clear and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

> https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html
>
> **Import a module for side-effects only**
>
> Though not recommended practice, some modules set up some global state that can be used by other modules. These modules may not have any exports, or the consumer is not interested in any of their exports. To import these modules, use:
>
> ```
> import "./my-module.js";
> ```